# Pose mode moving hair despite not having any weight painted on it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, weight-painting

So ive had this issue before and last time I just had to apply location but its not fixing it this time. Im pretty sure theres no weight painted on the hair so why is it still moving with the arm bones?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The vertex in my example has some weight on hand.R and thumb.L, so it moves when arms are moved.

[image]