# Why does the mesh move when there is no weights to it?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

*strong text*[image]When I move one bone, another part that has 0 weights towards that bone moves. I checked the zero weights and it shows that there is no weight towards it.[![Not rotated[[image: Rotated][1]]
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtpnYv5xTO9ygaN_h9N-qpQ021We8g?e=uMRTo8

Comment: Hello, maybe moving your bone moves another, and that other bone has influence on this part of your mesh

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285412/pose-mode-moving-hair-despite-not-having-any-weight-painted-on-it

Comment: if the comments above don't help, pls provide blend file because you didn't show us any of your settings

Comment: you will have to copy and paste the link

Comment: the linked file seems to be private or has missing access rights.

Comment: Hi, @DivinityBondZorrotheF0x .. please use https://blend-exchange.com/, and follow the instructions there.